# How can I pass a malloc'd address of arrays of pointers such that I can change the pointers in the arrays?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to to create the follow data structure:

`{}` = dynamic memory allocation

`[]` = array

`{[ptr, ptr, ptr], [ptr, ptr, ptr], ...}`

and a memory allocation to track the size of the memory locations that the `ptr`'s will point at:

`{[int, int, int], [int, int, int], ...}`

and then pass this data structure into a function such that the values of the inner `ptr`'s and `int`'s are changed from within the function.

I hoped something like this would work:

```
void foo(int **arr[3], int *sizes[3], int num_arrays)
{
  int i, j, k;
  for(i=0; i<num_arrays; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      sizes[i][j] = 1 + (i * j);
      arr[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes[i][j]);
      for(k=0; k<sizes[i][j]; k++)
      {
        arr[i][j][k] = i * j * k;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int **arr[3] = malloc(sizeof(*(int[3])) * 10); //line 33
  int *sizes[3] = malloc(sizeof(int[3]) * 10); //line 34
  foo(arr, sizes, 10);

  int i, j, k;
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      for(k=0; k<sizes[i][j]; k++)
      {
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j][k]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this results in compiler errors:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:33:41: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
   int **arr[3] = malloc(sizeof(*(int[3])) * 10);
                                         ^
main.c:34:19: error: invalid initializer
   int *sizes[3] = malloc(sizeof(int[3]) * 10);
```

Comment: Maybe try `typedef int INTARR3[3];`... you can then use things like `sizeof (INTARR3)` for size of an array with 3 ints.

Comment: @pmg see edit, didn't work.

Comment: works for me ... `typedef int INTARR3[3]; INTARR3 *a = malloc(4 * sizeof (INTARR3)); a[0][1] = 42;`

Comment: `int **arr[3]` declares an array with three elements, each of which is a pointer to pointer to int.

Comment: I don't know what the difference is, but I get `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
         arr[i][j][k] = i * j * k;`

Comment: You need to match the "dimensions" of the array to the amount of indexing. `int a[3] /* one dimension*/; int *b[3] /* two "dimensions" */; INTARR3 c /* one dimension */; INTARR3 *d /* two "dimensions" */; INTARR3 e[3] /* 2 dimensions */; INTARR3 **f /* 3 "dimensions" */;` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you can use type aliases (which I normally venomously object to regarding pointer aliasing) to make this at least readable. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define X_SIZE 3                 // our fixed internal size
typedef int INTARRX[X_SIZE];     // array of int
typedef int *INTPTRX[X_SIZE];    // array of pointer to int.

void foo(INTPTRX arr[], INTARRX sizes[], int num_arrays)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i<num_arrays; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<X_SIZE; j++)
        {
            sizes[i][j] = 1 + (i * j);
            arr[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes[i][j]);
            for (k = 0; k<sizes[i][j]; k++)
            {
                arr[i][j][k] = i * j * k;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    INTARRX *sizes = calloc(10, sizeof *sizes);
    INTPTRX *arr = calloc(10, sizeof *arr);

    foo(arr, sizes, 10);

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k<sizes[i][j]; k++)
            {
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0
0
0

0
0 1
0 2 4

0
0 2 4
0 4 8 12 16

0
0 3 6 9
0 6 12 18 24 30 36

0
0 4 8 12 16
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64

0
0 5 10 15 20 25
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

0
0 6 12 18 24 30 36
0 12 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120 132 144

0
0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49
0 14 28 42 56 70 84 98 112 126 140 154 168 182 196

0
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
0 16 32 48 64 80 96 112 128 144 160 176 192 208 224 240 256

0
0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
0 18 36 54 72 90 108 126 144 162 180 198 216 234 252 270 288 306 324
```

I could lose the aliases and just do everything long hand, but then you would have an entry for an obfuscation contest and not a reasonable piece of code.

---

**Without Type Aliases**

Included only for reference, the same code without the aliases. It should be readily apparent why, in this case, they actually help regarding clarity (and the only reason I would use them).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define X_SIZE 3            // our fixed internal size

void foo(int *(*arr)[X_SIZE], int (*sizes)[X_SIZE], int num_arrays)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i<num_arrays; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<X_SIZE; j++)
        {
            sizes[i][j] = 1 + (i * j);
            arr[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes[i][j]);
            for (k = 0; k<sizes[i][j]; k++)
            {
                arr[i][j][k] = i * j * k;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static const int N = 10;

    int (*sizes)[X_SIZE] = calloc(N, sizeof *sizes);
    int *(*arr)[X_SIZE] = calloc(N, sizeof *arr);

    foo(arr, sizes, N);

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<X_SIZE; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k<sizes[i][j]; k++)
            {
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say you venomously object to using this method. What would you prefer to do? Ultimately I need a dynamically decided multiple of 3 number of pointers, would it be better to just use: `int **arr = malloc(sizeof(*int) * X_SIZE * num)`?

Comment: @CSStudent7782 Its actually the hiding of pointer types in typedefs that I so strongly object to. They rarely if ever add clarity, and often hide it instead. In this case it isn't  pointer types being aliases, it's *array* types, and as such, i'd give it a pass. but when you see things like `typedef int * intp;` you'll discover it ultimately only makes the code harder, not easier, to read and manage.